# c# hide class members when exporting DLL

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly, ilasm

Can I only make some methods visible to the end user when I'm publishing a DLL to third party applications?

My code is built upon 7-8 different projects which **call each other**, they have different namespaces like "**Company.ProjectName**" which I think relate under the "**Company**" namespace, and I only want one of the projects (which has an interface defined BTW) to be visible to outer world.

Every project in the solution compiles into DLL's and then I'm combining them using ILASM.

BTW, there are other projects using these in the solution that are not related to this dll.

Edit: will the `internal` keyword work even if the namespaces are constructed like "**CompanyName.Project1**", "**CompanyName.Project2**" ? Will they see each other?

Comment: you can have all the class members as internals which you dont want to export

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to combine them, you just need a [friend assembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx):

> When you are developing a class library and additions to the library are contained in separate assemblies but require access to members in existing assemblies that are marked as Friend (Visual Basic) or internal (C#).
>   ...
>   Only assemblies that you explicitly specify as friends can access Friend (Visual Basic) or internal (C#) types and members.

The [*InternalsVisibleTo*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("AssemblyB")]
```

helps to lock it down so only the specified assembly can access the `internal` items.

(In answer to your edit: this is specified at the assembly level, it doesn't matter what the namespace is).

Comment: I've tried that with no luck. I wrote namespaces, classnames, everything to the `AssemblyB` parameter, but it won't work.

Comment: You need to show us specifically what didn't work - without that we can only guess what the problem is. Did you try this but still try to combine the assemblies?

Comment: I wrote it under the namespace, to the class, I moved it up to the namespace then it worked :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use `internal`

See the example below

```
public class MyPublicClass
{

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var myInternalClass = new MyInternalClass();
        myInternalClass.DoSomething();
    }
}

internal class MyInternalClass
{

    public void DoSomething()
    {
    }
}
```

In your DLL, `MyPublicClass` will be visible to external users - those who reference your DLL.

`MyInternalClass` will not be visible.